# How to set the productIdentifier in SKProduct object in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, skproduct

I have code like this:

```
SKProduct *product = [[SKProduct alloc] init];
```

And when I try to set price or the product identifier, I get a compile error saying that I can't set a read-only property.

This is how I try to set it:

```
product.productIdentifier = @"2";
```

What is the right way to set the price and productIdentifier for SKProduct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to set the price from your app. The `SKProduct` is used when you query for available in app purchases. The price is a readonly property which you might use to display the price of the IAP.

If you want to set the price you must do it from itunes connect where you defined your IAPs

Comment: Ah yes, good point. For some reason I spaced out on that. But what about passing the product identifier? How do I set that?

Comment: The product indentifier you also set in itunes connect to identify the purchase between other ones. Again you cannot set it from the code and you should use it only to differ between other purchases (best example is if you store it in user defaults so you could immediately enable the purchased content on app restart)

Comment: thank you, I am getting it now. So naturally, last question is how/where do I pull the list of products? I am following the raywenderlich tutorial for in-app purchases, but I am confused about how to pull the products.  Thanks :)

Comment: look for the method "requestProductsWithCompletionHandler". This is where the request for the IAP products is sent. On a successful call the didReceiveResponse method is called. You can see in his example how he iterates it and prints the products data.